# android geocoder : how to retrieve the name of the city in the local of the country of the city?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i use the android geocoder to retrieve the name of cities. however the name is returned in the local we use to construct the geocoder. is their any way to retrieve the name in the local of the city (exemple paris for paris in france or Москва for moscow in russia).

Comment: by passing your latlng you can get your city,local address ,postalcode etc

Comment: post your code....

Answer (score 0):

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
    if (addresses.size() > 0) 
    {
        System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
    }
    else
    {
       // do your staff
    }
```

Comment: Thanks mohd, but are you sure i will obtain Москва for moscow and 北京 for pekin? i think i will receive the name in my local :(

Answer (score 0):

try this you will get the complete address

```
private void getLocation(double lat, double lng) {
        try {
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                address.getAddressLine(0);
                address.getAddressLine(1);

                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");
                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append(" ");
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "strReturnedAddress : " + strReturnedAddress);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks akhilesh, but are you sure i will obtain Москва for moscow and 北京 for pekin? i think i will receive the name in my local :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Geocoder`'s [`getFromLocation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) method:

```
final LatLng        lLatLng     = new LatLng(0.0, 0.0);
final LatLng        lMaxResults = 10; 
final Geocoder      lGeocoder   = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);
final List<Address> lAddresses  = lGeocoder.getFromLocation(lLatLng.latitude, lLatLng.longitude, lMaxResults);
```

Comment: Thanks alex, but are you sure i will obtain Москва for moscow and 北京 for pekin? i think i will receive the name in English :(

Comment: Yeah that'll probably happen! That's where you change the `Locale`, like in [Mohd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8160620/mohd-saquib)'s answer. :)

Comment: but how to know the local for all country ?

Comment: `Locale.getDefault()` will return the `Locale` for the device you're currently using, so it will be suitable for that particular user.